# What are the rules for bitmasks? Like 0xFF vs. 0xFC

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit, bitmask

Im working on a game that creates Procedurally generated dungeons, I found an example that uses bit masking to retrieve things like room number and type of door.

In the example he uses a bitmask to pull details from the integer for each tile. and the integer is broken down like this

```
0xLLSDRRET

L - is the Level Number
S - Denotes a special tile(Like Stairs)
D - is if its a door, and what type(Door, Arch, Trapped)
R - Room number
E - Flags an entrance to a room
T - Names the type of tile(Floor, Cooridor, Blocked)
```

In this He uses a bit mask to get, for instance, the room number like:

```
int[][] map = new int[40][40] 
int $ROOM_ID = 0x0000FF00;
System.out.println(map[x][y] & $ROOM_ID);
```

Now with this if map[x][y] was for instance 0x00001200 the output would be 1200. This part of Masks I understand.

But in the source $ROOM_ID is ACTUALLY 0x0000FFC0 and I dont understand what the C does,because I tried diferent values and I cant seem to grab what the C does, for example

```
0x00001200 output-> 1200
0x00001210 output-> 1200
0x00001220 output-> 1200
0x00001230 output-> 1200
0x00001240 output-> 1240
0x00001250 output-> 1240
0x00001260 output-> 1240
0x00001270 output-> 1240
0x00001280 output-> 1280
0x00001290 output-> 1280
0x000012A0 output-> 1280
0x000012B0 output-> 1280
0x000012C0 output-> 12C0
0x000012D0 output-> 12C0
0x000012E0 output-> 12C0
0x000012F0 output-> 12C0
```

Can Someone with more knowledge of bitmasks explain why 0x0000FFC0 & 0x000012F0 = 12C0?

Comment: I reckon you'd be better off using an Enum for these sorts of flags, and then using EnumSet of any Enum where more than one flag can be active at a time. May not be as compact and memory frugal, but the code would be a lot more readable and therefore easier to write and test.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are doing is bitwise arithmetic. Ignore the high-order bits for now (since they are all 0's) and simply consider the two hexadecimal values `0xFFC0` and `0x12F0`. Then a `bitwise and` works exactly like multiplication in base 10. It will look like this on the bit level:

`0xFFC0 = 1111111111100000`

&

`0x12F0 = 0001001011110000`

This then equals `0001001011100000 = 0x12F0`

A trick to converting to and from hex-binary is this. Every two hex digits is a byte (i.e. 8 bits). For instance, `0xFF` is a single byte. Thus you can convert this to its binary representation by simply writing the bit-value for each hex digit (i.e. `0xF (base-16) = 1111 (base-2) = 15 (base-10)`). Since we know each byte is always exactly 8-bits, each hex digit converts to its own 4-bit binary representation. Then you only need to memorize binary representations for hexadecimal values `0000` (0) to `1111` (F) and replace them appropriately. The trick works in both directions.

As far as bitmasks go, this is simply useful for extracting values from a bitvector. A bitvector is (usually) a simple data type (i.e. `int`, `char`, etc.). Then, each particular bit signifies a type of value to enable or disable. So if I have a bitvector (char = single byte, so consider this data type for bitvector, for example) of `0x01` and my lowest-order bit signifies a door is enabled, then this bitvector has a door. If my bitvector's value is `0x02`, then there is no door enabled (but in `0x03` there is a door). Why is this? You need to always look at the underlying binary representation to fully understand a bitvector/bitmask.

`0x01 = 00000001`, `0x02 = 00000010`, `0x03 = 00000011`

As you can see, in the first and third values, the lowest-order bit is set. However, in the second value, the second lowest-order bit is set, but not the lowest-order. You can use this second value to signify another property, however (although for the purpose of example there is no door in the second value).

Then note, the corresponding bitmask (coincidentally) to retrieve a door from the bitvector formatted as above would be `0x01` since `0x01 & 0x01 = 1`, `0x02 & 0x01 = 0`, and `0x03 & 0x01 = 1` (again, return to the binary representation and multiply)

Comment: Gotcha, I was just missing why it was going 0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,8,8,8,8,C,C,C,C but makes sense now because the C makes the only options 0000, 0100, 1000, or 1100 since the last 2 binary would always be 00

Answer (score 6):

Pay attention to the binary, not just the hexadecimal.  `C` in hex is 12 in decimal is `1100` in binary; F is `1111` in binary.  So

F & 1 == 1, F & 2 == 2, C & F == C, 0 & 0 == 0.

Answer (score 1):

`0xF` is all `1` bits: `1111`. The bitwise *AND* of *any* value and `0xF` is the same value. In other words, an *AND* with `0xF` in a given position *preserves* the bits from the other operand.

So in `0x0000FFC0 & 0x000012F0`, the `F` digits are preserving the corresponding digits:

```
0xF & 0x1 = 0x1
0xF & 0x2 = 0x2
0xC & 0xF = 0xC
```

Similarly:

```
0xFFC0 & 0x12F0 = 0x12C0
```

As you probably know, the bitwise *AND* of any value and `0` is `0`. So constructs like `0x0000FF00` are used to preserve **only** the 2nd least significant byte.

The usage of `0xFFC0` really depends on how the rest of the code is using that least significant byte. In the explanation of the flags, the top half of the least significant byte is documented as: *an entrance to a room*. Somehow that's important in `System.out.println(map[x][y] & $ROOM_ID);`.

`0xC` is `1100` in binary, so by including `0xC0` in the `0xFFC0` mask, the code is also trying to preserve the two most significant bits of that least significant - rightmost - byte. Note that on those two bits you can encode exactly *4* values. This matches a game design with entrances possible on 4 compass points, if the game is 2D and each room is a square, Zork-style.

As for *the rules for bitmasks*, you could do worse that starting with the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation): it covers the basics pretty well. Ultimately this is all [boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_%28logic%29).